# How to know the elements of field generated by several roots

Tags: abstract-algebra

Note that the roots of $X^3-2$ are $\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2} \zeta,\sqrt[3]{2} \zeta^2$ where $\zeta=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Then $\mathbb{Q}$ adjoints with the root $\sqrt[3]{2}$ has elements of the form $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

We know that the splitting field of  $X^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2},i \sqrt{3})$. My question is: How do we know the splitting field is of the form? Can I write the splitting field as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2} \zeta,\sqrt[3]{2} \zeta^2)$? Are they the same?

Also, how do we 'see' the elements of field which adjoints with several roots? For example, elements of $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2},i\sqrt{3})$?

If more examples can be given then it would be better.

Comment: Actually, the splitting field of $x^3-2$ is $\Bbb(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$.

Comment: It would be a good exercise to check yourself if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2} \zeta,\sqrt[3]{2} \zeta^2)=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2},i \sqrt{3})$

Comment: what I notice that is that both $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $i \sqrt{3}$ spans the three roots. So I can just take both of them ?

Comment: If any extension of a field $F$ that contains $r$ and $s$ also contains $t$, $u$, and $v$, and any extension of $F$ that contains $t$, $u$, and $v$ also contains $r$ and $s$, then $F(r,s)=F(t,u,v)$.

Comment: Is it true to say that if $r$ and $s$ can be written as a linear combination of $t,u,v$ over $F$, then $F(r,s) \subset F(t,u,v)$?